# Pyspark dataframe, iterate between flags, based on group

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i need to create a counter between events on a pyspark dataframe, like this:

input:

```
+-------+----+------+  
|machine|date|event |
+-------+----+------+  
| M1    |DAY1|     1|
| M1    |DAY2|     0|
| M1    |DAY3|     0|
| M1    |DAY4|     1|
| M1    |DAY5|     0|
+-------+----+------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-------+----+------+----------------------+  
|machine|date|event |days since last event |
+-------+----+------+----------------------+  
| M1    |DAY1|     1|                     0|
| M1    |DAY2|     0|                     1|
| M1    |DAY3|     0|                     2|
| M1    |DAY4|     1|                     3|
| M1    |DAY5|     0|                     1|
+-------+----+------+----------------------+
```

I saw about [Window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) functions, but i can't figure out how to make an if statement, which restarts the counter after it stumble on another flag event.

Any ideas on how can i do it?

Comment: Do you need to groupby on the `machine` column or is the sequence of events independent of machines?

Comment: @pansen it's machine dependent, when machine group ends, the counter must be restarted too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use multiple window functions for this case. You can find my solution below

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> 
>>> df = sc.parallelize([
...     ('M1','DAY1',1),
...     ('M1','DAY2',0),
...     ('M1','DAY3',0),
...     ('M1','DAY4',1),
...     ('M1','DAY5',0)
...     ]).toDF(['machine','date','event'])
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+-------+----+-----+
|machine|date|event|
+-------+----+-----+
|     M1|DAY1|    1|
|     M1|DAY2|    0|
|     M1|DAY3|    0|
|     M1|DAY4|    1|
|     M1|DAY5|    0|
+-------+----+-----+

>>> window1 = Window.partitionBy('machine').orderBy('date')
>>> window2 = Window.partitionBy('machine','new_col').orderBy('date')
>>> 
>>> df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.sum(F.lag('event').over(window1)).over(window1))
>>> df = df.withColumn('days_since_last_event', F.when(F.isnull('new_col')==True,0).otherwise(F.rank().over(window2)))
>>> 
>>> df = df.drop('new_col')
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+-------+----+-----+---------------------+                                      
|machine|date|event|days_since_last_event|
+-------+----+-----+---------------------+
|     M1|DAY1|    1|                    0|
|     M1|DAY2|    0|                    1|
|     M1|DAY3|    0|                    2|
|     M1|DAY4|    1|                    3|
|     M1|DAY5|    0|                    1|
+-------+----+-----+---------------------+
```

Comment: Great solution! I like the usage of `rank` here.

Comment: Great solution @Ali, many thanks! But i still can't figure out how this works. Do you have some tutorial which i can read then understand how it's working under the hood? The official documentation and databricks post about it didn't was so didactic as i would like.

Comment: @LeandroHumb, there is a great tutorial about window functions below. I hope it would help you for understanding -- https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html